# Google mobile vision api camera source dim frames

Tags: android, android-camera, android-vision, text-recognition

I am trying to follow google codelabs about vision apis such as barcode and text detection; but i noticed that the camera preview is offering dim frames , i played a little bit and made a greater frame sizes but seems like the auto focus is not working; the device is android 5.1 powered and built in camera app gives nicer results.

My goal was to test if the api can detect small text sentences and it's not, other apps i downloaded for the sake of comparing work perfectly.

[image: built in camera][image]

How can i improve frames quality ? Is this caused by the use of the standard camera api and should be using camera2 api ?

Any hints are welcome , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally , playing around with focus mode values solved my issue, MACRO mode was the solution to my problem , however, i'am stil confused about Mode Auto wich shoukd work too.